# Chi-square distribution funtion in terms of finitely many elementary functions.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $F(x)=K_n \int_0^x u^{(n-2/2)}e^{-u/2} du$ when $x \geq 0$ and $F(x) = 0$ when $x < 0$, with $K_n=\frac{1}{2^{n/2} \Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}$ (chi-square distribution).

How to show that $F(x)$  can be expressed in terms of finitely many elementary functions (exponentials functions and powers of x)?

I have calculated the integral for n=2,4,6,8, respectively i got:
$K_2 \int_0^x u^{0}e^{-u/2} du= 1-e^{-x/2}$,$K_4 \int_0^x u^{1}e^{-u/2} du= 1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x/2}(x+2)$, $K_6 \int_0^x u^{2}e^{-u/2} du= 1-\frac{1}{8}e^{-x/2}(x(x+4)+8)$, $K_8 \int_0^x u^{3}e^{-u/2} du= 1-\frac{1}{42}e^{-x/2}(x(x(x+6)+24)+48)$.

I have noticed that the first adding, without multiplying by $K_n$, is multiplied in this way for respectively n=4,6,8: 2*2=4, 4*4=16, 16*6=96. So I concluded that it is multiplied by the value of previous n.

This is all that I could reach.

Comment: Hint: integrate by parts and get a recurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it this way:

Because n is par, then $\frac{n}{2}$ is integer. This integer (let's call him $a$) count $1, 2, 3, ...$; when $n$ is increasing $(2, 4, 6, ...)$.

So $F(x)$ becomes in $F(x)=K_{2a} \int_0^x u^{a-1} e^{-u/2} du$. Now, let's take $a-1=l$ and replace it $F(x)=K_{2(l+1)} \int_0^x u^l e^{-u/2} du$ (Notice that $ l=0,1,2,...$).

Let's see what $K_{2(l+1)}=\frac{1}{2^{l+1}\Gamma(l+1)}=\frac{1}{2^{l+1}l!}$ and $\int_0^x u^l e^{-u/2}=2^{l+1}(\Gamma(l+1)-\Gamma(l+1,\frac{x}{2}))=2^{l+1}(l!-\int_{x/2}^{\infty} t^l e^{-t} dt)$.

Then $F(x)=1-\frac{\int_{x/2}^{\infty} t^l e^{-t} dt}{l!}$. All that remains is to evaluate the integral